# Error in xpath compile evaluate query

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <DataType1>
      <val1 />
      <val2 />
   </DataType1>
   <DataType2>
      <val21 />
      <val22 />
      <RetrieveThis1>test1</RetrieveThis1>
      <RetrieveThis2>test2</RetrieveThis2>
      <RetrieveThis3>test3</RetrieveThis3>
   </DataType2>
</data>
```

I need to retrive values test1, test2 and test3 in java.
I am trying to use xPath queries as follows:

```
String test1Value = xpath.compile("/data/DataType2/RetrieveThis1").evaluate(inputXML);
String test2Value = xpath.compile("/data/DataType2/RetrieveThis2").evaluate(inputXML);
String test3Value = xpath.compile("/data/DataType2/RetrieveThis3").evaluate(inputXML);
```

It is not giving the result. Could you please suggest if XPathExpresstion I am passing in compile query is correct.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: any error or just empty results? how about `Node node = (Node) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(inputXML, XPathConstants.NODE); String value = node.getNodeValue();`

Comment: No luck. It is throwing ClassCastException :(

Comment: I have another work around. If we have entire XML in string. How do I find text between <RetrieveThis1> and </RetrieveThis1> using Java's string manipulation functions? Please please please help :'(

Comment: this is another question. Please find my answer below, it should work.

Comment: The problem is I have my XML file content inside a string and I am parsing it to XML as follows:     org.w3c.dom.Document XMLDomDocument = (org.w3c.dom.Document)builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(DomXMLAsString))); however as there is no XML file created as such, this statement is giving exception

Comment: I have edited my answer to address the possible encoding issue with StringReader

Comment: in particular you need to set the encoding on the input source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me

```
String documentXmlAsString = readSomeXMLFromString();
final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(documentXmlAsString));
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
final Document document = builder.parse(is);
final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
final String test3Value = xpath.compile("/data/DataType2/RetrieveThis3").evaluate(document);

System.out.println(test3Value);
```

will print test3

Comment: The problem is I have my XML file content inside a string and I am parsing it to XML as follows:     org.w3c.dom.Document XMLDomDocument = (org.w3c.dom.Document)builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(DomXMLAsString))); however as there is no XML file created as such, this statement is giving exception